# Outlier transformation or no transformation?

Tags: t-test, spss, outliers

I have two group's of 25 people each. I want to know if there a difference between them on a past experience of happiness . I have a test with 100 question in it and all question have an a and b answer. The test is also divided in 4 section.

There 10 result that you can analyses for this test; section 1a, 1b,2a, 2b,3a 3b,4a, 4b totala and totalb (sum).

I'm doing t-test on all those section and on the sum.

I have two outlier;
1-with section 1b the outlier affect the normaly
2-with section 4b that don't affect the normaly but if I transform with a SQRT or log it change the signification of the t-test a lot.

If I want to calcul the sum (total a and total b) I need to transform all the data, yes? Or can I transform for the individual analyse and use the no transform data to do the total?

Comment: How many respondents ? what is the purpose to do a t- test. third para of body is not clear.

Comment: Is it better like that?

Comment: Yes. Individual or aggregate analysis depends on particular objective. But do indicate reasons for transformation. Normality is not a basis for trasformation.

Comment: Sorry if I'm slow, I understand that I need to specify why I do the transformation because transformation need explanation, my question is more like ;can I transform the data for the individual analysis and use the not transform data to do the aggregate calcul? Would it respect the processus or would it be boggus?

Comment: Witout going into nuances , yes.